# Cast a boost::log::expressions::attr< std::string > to std::string

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

While using Boost.Log, I am trying to keep my `TimeStamp` formatter such as:

```
  logging::add_file_log
    (
     keywords::file_name = "my.log",
     keywords::format =
     (
      expr::stream
      << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      << "," << expr::attr< int >("Line")
      << " " << expr::attr< std::string >("File")
      << " " << logging::trivial::severity
      << " - " << expr::smessage
     )
    );
```

It is said that I cannot use the other form of formatter since I'll have much difficulties turning `"TimeStamp"` into my custom format:

```
static void my_formatter(logging::record_view const& rec, logging::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
  strm << logging::extract< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", rec);
```

will output something like: `2015-Jul-01 16:06:31.514053`, while I am only interested in: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. However the first form is extremely hard to use, for instance I am not able to cast an `expr::attr< std::string >` to a simple `std::string` for instance:

```
  logging::add_file_log
    (
     keywords::file_name = "my.log",
     keywords::format =
     (
      expr::stream
      << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      << "," << expr::attr< int >("Line")
      << " " << boost::filesystem::path(expr::attr< std::string >("File"))
        .filename().string()
      << " " << logging::trivial::severity
      << " - " << expr::smessage
     )
    );
```

The above code does not even compile.

Is there an easy way to both print `TimeStamp` using my custom format and at the same time use a custom cast to string to be able to use `boost::filesystem::path::filename()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. The key point to understand is that Boost.Log formatting expressions (as well as filters, by the way) are Boost.Phoenix lambda functions. As such you can inject your own functions in them using Boost.Phoenix constructs such as `boost::phoenix::bind`. See an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks.formatting_sink_backend), for instance. Your code would look something like this:

```
std::string file_basename(logging::value_ref< std::string > const& filename)
{
  // Check to see if the attribute value has been found
  if (filename)
    return boost::filesystem::path(filename.get()).filename().string();
  else
    return std::string();
}

// ...

logging::add_file_log
(
  keywords::file_name = "my.log",
  keywords::format =
  (
    expr::stream
      << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      << "," << expr::attr< int >("Line")
      << " " << boost::phoenix::bind(&file_basename, expr::attr< std::string >("File"))
      << " " << logging::trivial::severity
      << " - " << expr::smessage
  )
);
```

Another way to do that is to use attribute keywords and define an `operator<<` specific for the File attribute. You can find an example [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.attr.tags).

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_line, "Line", int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_file, "File", std::string)

namespace std {

logging::formatting_ostream& operator<<
(
  logging::formatting_ostream& strm,
  logging::to_log_manip< std::string, tag::a_file > const& manip
)
{
  strm << boost::filesystem::path(manip.get()).filename().string();
  return strm;
}

} // namespace std

// ...

logging::add_file_log
(
  keywords::file_name = "my.log",
  keywords::format =
  (
    expr::stream
      << expr::format_date_time(a_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      << "," << a_line
      << " " << a_file
      << " " << logging::trivial::severity
      << " - " << expr::smessage
  )
);
```

Notice that attribute keywords simplify expressions significantly.

Lastly, you can use [`wrap_formatter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/expressions/wrap_formatter_idp48923680.html) to inject your own function into the streaming expression. When it comes to formatting, `wrap_formatter` invokes your function providing it with the log record being formatted and the formatting stream. When your function returns the wrapper automatically returns the reference to the formatting stream so that the rest of the formatting expression can proceed.

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_line, "Line", int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_file, "File", std::string)

void file_basename(logging::record_view const& record, logging::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
  // Check to see if the attribute value has been found
  logging::value_ref< std::string, tag::a_file > filename = record[a_file];
  if (filename)
    strm << boost::filesystem::path(filename.get()).filename().string();
}

// ...

logging::add_file_log
(
  keywords::file_name = "my.log",
  keywords::format =
  (
    expr::stream
      << expr::format_date_time(a_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
      << "," << a_line
      << " " << expr::wrap_formatter(&file_basename)
      << " " << logging::trivial::severity
      << " - " << expr::smessage
  )
);
```

The above is similar to the first variant with `boost::phoenix::bind` but allows for more flexibility in the `file_basename` implementation.

Comment: Your second solution does not work (using boost 1.55 on fedora amd64). If you make the function `static`, the compiler will let you know that `operator<<` is never used. My guess is that ADL picks another `operator<<` first.

Comment: Yes, the operator has to be in the namespace of the type being formatted - namespace std in this case. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

In custom formatter you can easily build the timestamp in `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` format:

```
void my_formatter(logging::record_view const& rec, logging::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
    const boost::posix_time::ptime &pt = *logging::extract< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", rec);
    strm << pt.date() << " " << pt.time_of_day().hours() << ":" << pt.time_of_day().minutes() << ":" << pt.time_of_day().seconds()
    ...
    << rec[expr::smessage];
}
```

Comment: Don't use need to use `setfill('0')` ?