# How to use Boost.Log formatting expressions in custom formatting function

Tags: c++, boost-log

I am trying to use a custom formatter with Boost.Log. The way I know how to do this is to call the `set_formatter` method of a sink giving it the address of a local function where the signature of the local function needs to be:

```
void my_formatter(boost::log::record_view const& rec, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)
```

In `my_formatter` I can use the Boost.Log extraction api to get the attribute values that I need. Once I get the values, I can output them to the `strm`. I want to do this so I can easily format some custom attributes stored in the record. But for other, more conventional Boost.Log attributes, I would like to continue to use the simple formatting expressions that are documented as keyword arguments to the `set_formatter` method. Is there a way to also use the keyword expressions in `my_formatter` custom function?

For example:

```
void my_formatter(boost::log::record_view const& rec, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
    // here I can get the timestamp attribute and format its ticks value to the stream
    boost::log::value_ref<boost::posix_time::ptime> tstamp_ref =
        boost::log::extract<boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", rec);
    const boost::posix_time::ptime& timestamp = tstamp_ref.get();

    strm << timestamp.time_of_day().ticks();
}
```

Then given a sink, I can call

```
sink->set_formatter(&my_formatter)
```

But Boost.Log gives me an elegant (almost magical) expression that I can use to set the formatter:

```
boost::log::formatter formatter =
    expr::stream
    << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>(
        "TimeStamp", "%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S.%f, ");

sink->set_formatter(formatter)
```

My question is: is there a way to use the formatter expression in my custom `my_formatter` function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do is to inject your custom parts of the formatter into the formatting expression created with Boost.Log instead of the other way around. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163790/cast-a-boostlogexpressionsattr-stdstring-to-stdstring/31171443#31171443) answer describes a way to achieve that by using `phoenix::bind`.

Comment: Thanks! That is a long answer, so I will have to study it a little, but that seems like a good approach too. Can you discuss a little more the performance slowdowns when using the formatting expressions? You mention in the docs that the formatting expressions in code will perform faster than ones created from a config file. My observation is that my non-expression formatter performs faster than the expression based one. (Granted, in my ad-hoc benchmark the only work being done is logging, so I am being hyper-critical regarding the slowdown, but sometimes performance really does matter.)

Comment: One would have to examine the code and the generated assembly to discover the reason of performance regression. The formatting expressions (the ones involving `expr::stream` anyway) are more efficient than the parsed formatters because the compiler has more ways to optimize. In particular it can inline functions more aggressively. A hand written formatter can potentially outperform the formatting expression because it can be more specialized. It's usually a flat function, so it doesn't depend on inlining that much, while the compiler may fail to optimize template expressions for some reason.

Comment: Also, if your formatter involves date/time then make sure you use `expr::format_date_time` and not the `operator<<` from Boost.DateTime as the latter is known to be slower.

Answer (score 3):

After some work, I found some Boost.Log test code, [form_date_time.cpp](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/develop/test/run/form_date_time.cpp#L152), that shows how to do this. Below is how to use the expression formatter programmatically in a custom format function.

```
void my_formatter(boost::log::record_view const& rec,
                  boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)
{
    typedef boost::log::formatter formatter;
    formatter f = expr::stream << expr::format_date_time<boost::posix_time::ptime>(
                      "TimeStamp", "%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M:%S.%f, ");
    f(rec, strm);
}
```

While I have given the answer, one should careful on using it. In my benchmarking tests, a properly implemented custom formatter function will outperform the expression formatter. But for complex expressions that you do not want to write code for (e.g., the specialized [Named scope formatter](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.formatters.named_scope)), this approach allows one to take advantage of an expression formatter in a custom formatter function.